# Measure execution time of async method

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-async, deferred-result

I have async method where I use DeferredResult as return type. I want write junit test for that method where I call this method in loop, e.g 100 times, and I need measure execution time for every call of that method.

Here is method sample:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Override
public DeferredResult foo() {
    DeferredResult dr = new DeferredResult(5000L, "timeout");
    dr.onCompletion(() -> {
        // do some stuff
    });
    deferredResults.add(dr);

    return dr;        
}
```

created deferredResult I add into collection, and I iterate that collection in another method where I set some result, and then is dr returned.

Can you show my how should looks like test where I will be able measure execution time of multiple calls of that method?

```
@Test
public void executionTimeTest() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        asyncService.foo();
    }

    // here I need get execution time for each call
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to solve this question is adding additional data in DeferredResult class as it is recommended by [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/async/DeferredResult.html). Precisely, the following sentence in spring docs points out this possibility.

> Subclasses can extend this class to easily associate additional data
>   or behavior with the DeferredResult. For example, one might want to
>   associate the user used to create the DeferredResult by extending the
>   class and adding an additional property for the user. In this way, the
>   user could easily be accessed later without the need to use a data
>   structure to do the mapping.

Given this possibility, you can extend the DeferredResult and add a start and end time:

```
public class MyDeferredResult extends DeferredResult {

    long startTime;
    long endTime;

    public MyDeferredResult(Long timeout, Object timeoutResult) {
        super(timeout, timeoutResult);
        this.startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean setResult(Object result) {
        boolean r = super.setResult(result);
        this.endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return r;
    }

    public long totalTime() {
        return (endTime - startTime)/1000;
    }

}
```

Then, your Async Service can be similar to this one:

```
 public MyDeferredResult foo() {
    MyDeferredResult dr = new MyDeferredResult(5000L, "timeout");
    new Thread(() -> {
        Random r = new Random();
        System.out.println("async task started");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(r.nextInt(4) * 1000 );
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("async task finished");
        dr.setResult("test async result");
    }).start();
    deferredResults.add(dr);
    return dr;
}

boolean hasResults() {
    boolean result = true;
    for(MyDeferredResult dr: deferredResults) {
        result = result && dr.hasResult();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Finally, in your test, you can retrieve the total time of each execution:

```
   @Test
    public void executionTimeTest() {
        Service service = new Service();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            service.foo();
        }

       while (!service.hasResults()) {
            System.out.println("No result yet");
       }

        for(MyDeferredResult dr: service.deferredResults) {
            System.out.println(dr.totalTime());
        }
    }
```